# Regex not returning any matches independent of expression used

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

Ok here is the issue, I have been trying to build cURL script to check for dead links in a database. The links all look something like this `http://www.ltblekinge.se/download/18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750`. The issue that I have is that no mater what regex "pattern" I use the `$url_list` remains empty. Any help would be appreciated!

**Problematic part of Code**

```
<?php
/*Config*/
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'root';
/*curl setup of varibles*/
$excluded_domains = array(  
'localhost', 'rollnstroll.se');
$max_connections = 10;
$url_list = array();  
$working_urls = array();  
$dead_urls = array();  
$not_found_urls = array();  
$active = null;



try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=blankett", $username, $password);
$dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


/*** fetch into an PDOStatement object ***/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `forms2`";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forms2");
$stmt->execute();

while ($d = $stmt->fetchAll()) {

    if (preg_match_all('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/', $d['link_forms'], $matches)) {

/***error code***/
if (preg_last_error() == PREG_NO_ERROR) {
print 'There is no error.';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
print 'There is an internal error!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) {
print 'Backtrack limit was exhausted!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR) {
print 'Recursion limit was exhausted!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
print 'Bad UTF8 error!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
print 'Bad UTF8 offset error!';
}

    foreach ($matches[1] as $url) { 



        // exclude some domains  
        $tmp = parse_url($url);  
        if (in_array($tmp['host'], $excluded_domains)) {  
            continue;  
        }
        // store the url  
        $url_list []= $url; 
    }
   }
}

// remove duplicates  
$url_list = array_values(array_unique($url_list));

if (!$url_list) {  
die('No URL to check');  
}  


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**DB Structure**

```
1 id    int(10) No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2 master_id     int(10) No  None
3   name_form   varchar(500) latin1_swedish_ci No   None
4   link_form   varchar(500)    latin1_swedish_ci No    None
5   date_added  timestamp   No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**Question**
Why is `$url_list`emtpy?

Comment: var_dump($matches[1]) == ?

Comment: also - unless you're 100% about that regexp, try preg_last_error() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php

Comment: found the regexp at http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the

Comment: try single quoting the regexp, your $s could be it.

Comment: @TasosBitsios I think I don´t understand you. If there is anything you want me to clarify, please tell me.

Comment: @TasosBitsios using ' instead of " did not work.

Comment: Why do you need to match the url. the column `form_link` is already an url right? The regex is probably not even required. Just parse the link.

Comment: OK - there's another problem with your regexp then. After the if() block, output preg_last_error() (should be an integer number) and look up the error code here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.constants.php

Comment: @Bart You are right, I don´t need to match. But I want to learn how to use regex at the same time.

Comment: @StenW It's better to learn where to **not** use regex. Most of the time they are not needed at all. Also, if you want to learn try something simpler. That regex is way complex. At least for me it is :-)

Comment: Well it was not that complex when I started, but now I am on a quest to solve this b-s. Giving up is not in my nature.

Comment: Hm. Seems to be working for me now, see below.

Comment: Cool, the error code gave me nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$url="http://www.ltblekinge.se/download/18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750 http://one.com www.two.com http://yourad.io";

preg_match_all('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/', $url, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.ltblekinge.se/download/18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750
    [1] => http://one.com
    [2] => www.two.com
    [3] => http://yourad.io
)
```

Check the contents of your  `$d['link_forms']`

Comment: Ok, I think you where right. Its the first time I used preg_match_all and I was a little confused about its workings. Thanks man!