# Regex not returning matches from database, but works fine when manually put in to input string

Tags: php, regex

I know I asked a question yesterday about regex ([Regex not returning any matches independent of expression used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429808/regex-not-returning-any-matches-independent-of-expression-used)). The code that I got yesterday works fine as long as I put all the URL:s into the input string manually, but when I load it from my database I get zero matches.

**Functioning code**

```
$url = "http://www.ltblekinge.se/download/18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750 http://one.com www.two.com http://yourad.io";

preg_match_all('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/', $url,  $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

gives the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.ltblekinge.se/download/18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750 [1] => http://one.com [2] => www.two.com [3] => http://yourad.io )
```

**Non functional code**

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'root';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'root';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=blankett", $username, $password);
$dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT link_form FROM forms2");
$stmt->execute();
$url = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

preg_match_all('/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/', $url, $matches);

if (preg_last_error() == PREG_NO_ERROR) {
print 'There is no error.';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
print 'There is an internal error!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) {
print 'Backtrack limit was exhausted!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR) {
print 'Recursion limit was exhausted!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
print 'Bad UTF8 error!';
}
else if (preg_last_error() == PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
print 'Bad UTF8 offset error!';
}

print_r($matches);


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

gives me the output:

```
There is no error.
```

This makes me think there is something wrong with my input string, but I can no figure out what is wrong with it. This is what my input string looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.ltblekinge.se/download /18.9c16a31109c04a3e880003750/forskrivningsanvisn_rorelse_forflyttn ) [1] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.ltdalarna.se/upload/vard_och_halsa/halso_och_sjukvarden/ldhjalpmedel/Hjalpmedelsguide/03Hjmhantering/Hantering%20av%20kostnader%20fÃ¶r%20hjÃ¤lpmedel%20ver%202.pdf ) [2] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.gotland.se/imcms/62373 ) [3] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.hjalpnu.se/download/18.4fd9e13012a408581b980002702/bestallningsblankett.doc ) [4] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.regionhalland.se/PageFiles/14881/Bil%20A%2013%20FÃ¶rskrivning%20av%20hjÃ¤lpmedel.pdf ) [5] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.jll.se/download/18.5c5942f112d4af0bbaf80008216/FrÃ¥gor+och+svar+-+brukare.pdf ) [6] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.jll.se/download/18.5c5942f112d4af0bbaf80008218/RÃ¥dgivning+hjÃ¤lpmedel.pdf ) [7] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.jll.se/download/18.47d2594d12bccf68c3680001577/Definition+och+direktiv+egenansvar+och+hjÃ¤ ) [8] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.jll.se/download/18.2a18114134d5722c50800050/Fakturaunderlag+fÃ¶r+brukare+120112.pdf ) [9] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lj.se/info_files/infosida38484/lanevillkor_hjalpmedel.pdf ) [10] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lj.se/info_files/infosida38484/avvikelserapport.doc ) [11] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.ltkronoberg.se/upload/Dokument/Halsa_och_vard/Hitta_ratt_i_varden/Funktionshinder/Hjalpmedel/FÃ¶rskrivningsblankett.DOC ) [12] => Array ( [link_form] => https://www.nllplus.se/upload/IB/pv/hjpmk/blanketter/SÃ¤rskild%20fÃ¶rskrivning.pdf ) [13] => Array ( [link_form] => https://www.nllplus.se/upload/IB/pv/hjpmk/HjÃ¤lpmedelsportalen/Lathund%20sÃ¤rskild%20fÃ¶rskrivning.doc ) [14] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.skane.se/Public/HAB/Hjalpmedelshandbok/100-allmanna-riktlinjer.pdf ) [15] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.slso.sll.se/upload/Hjalpmedel_Stockholm/Blanketter/Enstaka%20produkt%202012-12-04.doc ) [16] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.liv.se/sidkat/4072/Regelverk%20OTA%20090205.pdf ) [17] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.liv.se/sidkat/4072/Skrivelse%20gallande%20upphandling-05.doc ) [18] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.liv.se/sidkat/4072/RemissOTA.pdf ) [19] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lvn.se/pagefiles/2548/fillistning/riktlinjer%20fÃ¶r%20fÃ¶rskrivning%20av%20hjÃ¤lpmedel%20i%20landstinget%20vÃ¤sternorrland%20pdf.pdf ) [20] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lvn.se/pagefiles/12448/flÃ¶desschema%20ordnat%20infÃ¶rande%20produktgrupp_20111025.pdf ) [21] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lvn.se/PageFiles/6071/Blanketter/BestÃ¤llningsblanketter/BestÃ¤llning%20Medicintekniska%20hjÃ¤lpmedel,%20120316.pdf ) [22] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lvn.se/PageFiles/6071/Blanketter/BestÃ¤llningsblanketter/Bilaga%20B,%20hjÃ¤lpmedel%20fÃ¶r%20stÃ¥%20och%20gÃ¥%20120313.pdf ) [23] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.vgregion.se/sv/Omrade-Hjalpmedel/Har-du-en-ide-om-vad-vi-kan-gora-battre/Synpunkter-pa-Hjalpmedelscentralernas-sortiment/ ) [24] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.vgregion.se/upload/Handbok%20fÃ¶r%20fÃ¶rskrivning%20av%20personliga%20hjÃ¤lpmedel/HjÃ¤lpmedelsansÃ¶kan%20Gbg%202011-02-22.doc ) [25] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.orebroll.se/Files-sv/Ã–rebro%20lÃ¤ns%20landsting/VÃ¥rd%20och%20hÃ¤lsa/Habilitering/Centrum%20fÃ¶r%20hjÃ¤lpmedel/FÃ¶rskrivarportal/Blanketter/FÃ¶rskrivning%20av%20tekniska%20hjÃ¤lpmedel.doc ) [26] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lio.se/Patientinformation/Hjalpmedel-och-handikappservice/Hjalpmedelsforskrivning/Forskrivningsratt-for-hjalpmedel/ ) [27] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lio.se/pages/37692/Behorighet%20bestallare%20landsting.pdf ) [28] => Array ( [link_form] => http://www.lio.se/pages/37692/behorighet%20Forskr%20landsting%2020090702.pdf ) ) There is no error.
```

**Question**
What is wrong with the input string and why is there no matches?

Comment: Yes, does that mean that I can´t have an array of arrays?

Comment: from: [prag_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) second parameter (subject) should be string,not array.

Comment: @StenW Check the manual for `preg_match_all`. It will say the second parameter should be a string. Any other time you're in doubt: check the manual first.

Comment: @StenW - That's exactly what [the docs](http://es1.php.net/preg_match_all) say.

Comment: Lovely, I am kind of new to PHP and makes mistakes.

Comment: @StenW How many times are you going to ask a question regarding the same regex where it is again not needed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429808/regex-not-returning-any-matches-independent-of-expression-used

Comment: Well Bart, you are indeed right. Hopefully my stupid question will help someone else not make the same mistake.

Comment: @StenW I have no problem with someone being a newbie. Just take my advice and read the manual first. Then read it again.

Comment: I think that is the right approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input string is not a string, it's an array.

```
foreach ($url as $u) {
    preg_match_all(..., $u['link_form'], $matches);
}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for asking an obvious